# Seg fault in copy constructor doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

So, when I try to set the data of newPtr equal to the data of origPtr, I receive a seg fault within the first lopp of the for-control-structure. I'm not sure what is causing it. Is this maybe a misuse of my pointers? Or a typo? Or perhaps a range error in my for loop's idiom?

```
List::List(const List &aList): numNodes(aList.numNodes) {
    empty = true;
    forward = true;
    string flag;

    cout << "Copy from head to tail? (y/n): ";
    cin >> flag;
    if(flag=="n")
        forward = false;

    if(!aList.head) {
        head = NULL; //aList is empty. so is this->List.
        tail = NULL;
    } else { // copy 1st Node.
        head = new Node;
        if(forward)
            head->setData(aList.head->getData());
        else // copy in reverse.
            head->setData(aList.tail->getData());
        //copy rest of List.
        Node *newPtr = head; //newPtr points to last Node in new List.

        //origPtr points to nodes in original List.
        if(forward) {
            cout << "Copying normally...\n" << endl;
            for(Node *origPtr=aList.head->getNext(); origPtr!=NULL;
                origPtr=origPtr->getNext()) {
                newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
                newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
            } // end for
            cout << "3" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Copying in reverse order...\n" << endl;
            for(Node *origPtr=aList.tail->getPrev(); origPtr!=NULL;
                origPtr=origPtr->getPrev()) {
                newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
                newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
            } // end for
        } // end if/else
        newPtr->setNext(NULL);
    } // end if/else
    cout << "Done copying!\n" << endl;
} // end copy constructor
```

If more code is necessary, I will make the necessary edits.

Also, I am aware that the standard for c++11 is to use nullptr. I will not be using it for this implementation. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc-v4.6.3, which does not support c++11.

**EDIT:** Thanks guys! So I added 3 lines to my for loops before newPtr points to getNext(). I declared newNode as a Node pointer pointing to NULL on the next line after I define newPtr as pointing to head.

```
            newNode = new Node;
            newNode->setPrev(newPtr);
            newPtr->setNext(newNode);
```

Comment: If you get a set fault there, it should mean that either newPtr or origPtr is invalid at that point. What happens when you call `getNext` on the newly created `Node`, which doesn't have any syccessors? Does that return something valid?

Comment: I suspect we'd need to see the code for Node to say what's up

Comment: I/O in the copy constructor? Do you *really* want to ask the user what to do *every time* you copy a list, such as when you pass one to, or return one from, a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us analyze the following code.

```
  head = new Node;
    if(forward)
        head->setData(aList.head->getData());
    else // copy in reverse.
        head->setData(aList.tail->getData());
    //copy rest of List.
    Node *newPtr = head; //newPtr points to last Node in new List.
```

Here, you creating an object of Node and assigning it to head. Then you are setting the last or first data of list in head pointer. Then assing newPtr to head. So till now newPtr is pointing to just one element of list.

Next let us analyze following code.

```
} else {
    cout << "Copying in reverse order...\n" << endl;
    for(Node *origPtr=aList.tail->getPrev(); origPtr!=NULL;
        origPtr=origPtr->getPrev()) {
        newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
        newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
    } // end for
```

Here you are doing

```
newPtr = newPtr->getNext()
```

Now, since newPtr is just pointing to one element. After this operation, newPtr becomes null. Now, with newPtr being null, following is bound to crash

```
newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
```

You must allocate the memory for next element before doing newPtr->getNext().

Answer (score 2):

You do this

```
head = new Node;
//...
Node *newPtr = head; //newPtr points to last Node in new List.
```

then

```
newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
```

but don't set the next pointer on the node, unless there is magic going on in the `Node` code we can't see. I suspect the getNext gives you back a `NULL` `Node` which causes the seg fault.
It makes more sense to set the data first, then point at the next node, then move to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(Node *origPtr=aList.head->getNext(); origPtr!=NULL;
                origPtr=origPtr->getNext()) {
     newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
     newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData()); //SEG FAULT
   } // end for
```

The problem that I see is that you are not allocating new memory for the new list that you are creating. You have only created new memory for the head node.

Something like:

```
for(Node *origPtr=aList.head->getNext(); origPtr!=NULL;
                origPtr=origPtr->getNext()) {
     Node *temp = new Node;
     newPtr->next = temp; // assuming you have next as a member of the class Node.
     newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
     newPtr->setData(origPtr->getData());
   } // end for
```